# Issue compiling kernel modules

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, ubuntu-12.10

I bought a new Toshiba Satellite C855 and installed Ubuntu 12.10 on it only to find that the preinstalled drivers for wifi and ethernet do not work. As a result, this new computer has absolutely no internet access. I downloaded the source for the correct drivers and I am currently working on installing them. When I build the modules I get the following error

```
make -C /lib/modules/3.5.0-17-generic/build M=/home/<user>/Desktop/rtl_92ce_92se_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013 modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/lib/modules/3.5.0-17-generic/build`
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `modules'. Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/lib/modules/3.5.0-17-generic/build`
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I had to make the `/lib/modules/3.5.0-17-generic/build` directory. I DO have the headers installed (at `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-17/`). I have also done a lot of googling on this subject before posting this question, but everything I found was either dead or left unanswered.

Note: I would much rather avoid showing outputs. Since this computer that I am posting from is not the Toshiba machine and the new machine does not have internet access, I have to manually type outputs or hassle with a flash drive. Also, if I need any to install any packages, I also need links to .deb packages, not apt-get install commands.

Thanks ahead.

Comment: Do you have the build-essential package?

Comment: Do make modules-prepare

Comment: `make modules-prepare` just said no rule for target. Build-essential was not installed, but it is now and there has been no change. Still says no rule to both.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix it on my own and figured I'd post my solution:

In my original question I said that I had to mkdir the build directory. What I didn't realize was this was supposed to be a symlink to the kernel source directory. Once I did that, everything (including my ethernet, wifi is still a bit iffy) suddenly works.

Answer (score 0):

I would advice you to stop your efforts compiling this on the destination PC.
you are missing all the essential tools to compile the kernel, and obtaining them without an Internet connection is a tedious job, handling all dependencies, it's a nightmare.

You have two options:

1. Search for a binary module, that was pre-compiled for you target PC.
2. Compile it yourself, on another machine, I would suggest doing it under virtualbox / vmware, so you can install the exact version of Ubuntu, you're trying to compile for. then just copy the `.ko` to your target, `insmod`, and you're ready to go.

Comment: Does `insmod` have to be manually run to load the module or is there somewhere I can 'drop' the .ko so that it is automatically loaded on boot?

Comment: insmod has to be launched manually, there are of course other ways to achieve what you want, google it.

Comment: This isn't a response, so much as it is an answer for other people reading this question trying to find an answer:

`/etc/modules` or `/etc/modules.conf`: Add the module to the list and it will be loaded during the boot sequence.